# как найти количество пропущенных чисел в массиве

Tags: javascript

```js
x=[2,4,6]
```

например в этом массиве начиная с первого элемента отсутствует 2 числа։3 и 5, нужно вывести количество отсутствующих т.е. 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так։

```js
var x = [2,4,6];

var m = [];
var maxCount = Math.max.apply(Math, x);
var mincount = Math.min.apply(Math, x);


for (var i = mincount; i < maxCount; i++) {
  if (x.indexOf(i) == -1) {
    m.push(i);
  }
}

/*Сам массив*/
console.log(m);

/*Количество элементов*/
console.log(m.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let x = [2,4,6],
max = Math.max(...x), //в этой строке мы находим максимальное число 
min = Math.min(...x); //в этой строке мы находим минимальное число 
let result = [... new Array(max-min+1)] //здесь формируем массив конструктором и распаковываем его в обычный массив (это важно сделать для корректной работы методов)
    .map((_, i)=>min+i) // здесь мы формируем массив со всеми значениями
    .filter(elem=>!x.includes(elem)).length // исключаем значения из начального массива и определяем его длинну.
```

p.s. Можно просто вычесть длинну изначального списка и разность максимального и минимального, но в этом случае мы лишаем себя возможности работать с элементами.

Если строго по задаче, то достаточно сделать следующее

```
let x = [2,4,6],
max = Math.max(...x), 
min = Math.min(...x); 
console.log(max-min+1 - x.length)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]